# How do I understand if an indefinite integral is not solvable in terms of elementary functions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals, elementary-functions

Many indefinite integrals cant be solved in terms of elementary functions.e.g.-$$\int \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$$
But many hard looking ones are still solvable by weird substitutions and other tricks.
Is there a test(like there are tests of solvability/convergence.etc in mathematics) of whether it is solvable or not by which I can see beforehand without wasting hours of time after which I come to know that it is not even solvable?

Comment: This kind of question falls into the domain of "Differential Galois theory." The answer is given by [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)). A more thorough presentation [is given here](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/a.debray/lecture_notes/u19_differential_Galois_theory.pdf).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral

Duplicate

Comment: @BenGrossmann: unfortunately, this material is inaccessible to most mortals :-(